# Clear cells in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

Here's what I've got

```js
function clearRange() {

    var AUTH_TOKEN = "Enter your OAuth_Token";
    var url = "placeholder url";
    var auth = "AuthSub token=\"" + AUTH_TOKEN + "\"";
    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
        headers: {
            Authorization: auth
        }
    });
    UrlFetchApp.getRequest("placeholder url");

    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var response = ui.alert('Do you have a Gmail Account? (Choose "No" if you are not signed in.)', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

    if (response == ui.Button.YES) {

        var attachments = [{
            fileName: "Innevape Wholesale Order Form.xlsx",
            content: res.getContent(),
            mimeType: "application/vnd.ms-excel"
        }];
        MailApp.sendEmail("placeholder email", "Innevape Wholesale Order", "", {
            attachments: attachments
        });

        var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
        var sent = ui.alert("Email Sent!", ui.Button.OK);

    } else {

        showURL("placeholder url");

        function showURL(href) {
            var app = UiApp.createApplication().setHeight(35).setWidth(90);
            app.setTitle("Thank You!");
            var link = app.createAnchor("Download File", href).setId("link");
            app.add(link);
            var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
            doc.show(app);
        }
    }

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Mix Sheet');
    sheet.getRange('B3:F29').clearContent();
}
```

The code is attached to a button on my spreadsheet that is supposed to bring open a box asking whether or not they have a gmail account. If they choose "Yes" then it should send the email to me and give them a confirmation window saying "Email Sent!". If they choose "No" then I want it to bring up a box to download the file so they can email it on their own. After all of that it should clear the designated cells.

If you choose "No" it says

> "TypeError: showURL is not a function, it is undefined."

If "Yes" it sends the email but says

> "Cannot find method alert(string,Button)."

Neither choice currently clears the cells.